# passing and returning vectors to a function in C++

Tags: c++, function, vector

I have a function:

```
void computeC(array3D fp, double& C) {
C = 0.0;
for (int x = 0; x < M; ++x) {
    for (int y = 0; y < N; ++y) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            C += fp[x][y][i];
        }
    }
}
}
```

here the variable fp and C are defined as:

```
typedef std::vector<double> array1D;
typedef std::vector<array1D> array2D;
typedef std::vector<array2D> array3D;
array2D C(M, array1D(N, 0));
array3D fp(M, array2D(N, array1D(5, 0.0)));
```

The function is a called as:

```
computeC(fp, C);
```

When I execute the main code, following error appears:

```
vect.cpp:9:22: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'double&' 
from expression of type 'array2D {aka std::vector<std::vector<double> >}'
```

and

```
vect.hpp:130:6: error: in passing argument 2 of 'void computeRho(array3D, double&)'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Surprisingly, `double&` is different type from `array2D`.

Comment: Did you read the error message? It says exactly what the problem is.

Comment: `void computeC(array3D fp, double& C)`  Even if you get the second argument working, you should be passing the first argument by reference, not by value.

Comment: PaulMckenzie..Still same error by trying your suggestion.

Comment: My suggestion has to do with unnecessary copying of a 3d vector.  If you pass it by reference, the copy isn't done.

Comment: @TheCoder - what du you expect your `computeC` function to do? Currently it calculates the sum of all elements in the 3D array and has nothing to do with the 2D array.  Is that you want it to do?

Comment: @StillLearning: Yes, it will calculate sum of all elements of 3D array and store it in a 2D array.

Comment: @TheCoder - so you want all elements in the 2D array to be set to the sum of all elements in the 3D array?

Comment: @StillLearning:Yes, you get the point, this what "exactly" I want. This function then will be a part of a loop, where at each iteration value of 2D array updated as 3D array changes it values.

Comment: @TheCoder - I'm not sure yet exactly what you are looking for but I tried to update my answer.

Comment: @TheCoder: Can you post the loop that calls this function? A better understanding of your problem may help finding a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler message is quite clear. The type of the second parameter that you try to pass to the function does match with the type the parameter is declared to have. The type of the parameter is `double&` but you try pass an `array2D`. `array2D` is not a `double`, so you may not pass it to the function.

To solve this, define `C` to be a `double`.

> But array2D is a vector of vector of doubles. how can I again define C as double?

You can do this by removing the definition `array2D C(M, array1D(N, 0));` and replacing it with `double C = 0.0;`

> Any other idea of function definition with vectors as input and output arguments?

Yes, that's another possible approach. Instead of defining a function that takes a `double&` as a parameter, you could instead implement a function that does take an `array2D&` parameter. You could then pass `C` to such function.

Comment: But array2D is a vector of vector of doubles. how can I again define `C` as `double`?

Comment: `C` is 2D array and its value will change during the code execution. I have defined `array2D C(M, array1D(N, 0));` in **global scope** and my code is using on other places as well. Any other idea of function definition with vectors as input and output arguments?

Comment: @TheCoder `C is 2D array` that's exactly the problem. If `C` is a 2D array, then you simply can not pass it to a function that doesn't take a 2D array.

Comment: It's completely unclear what you expect the code to do, so you will have to _explain it_, @TheCoder. Your function takes a `double`, but you are giving it some other thing. What did you expect? And when you ask us for help, _what do you want us to do_?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The code have to take a 3D array (vector of vector of vector as I defined) and a 2D array (vector of vector as  defined). The 2D array will update during code execution, however, 3D array is used to calculate the 2D array. I wrote a function, that is giving me the said error. I want to remove the error and wish to define the function that I have not to change my array definition rather to modify function. I need help from you guys to either complete modification or to change some part of the existing function, to make the code work.

Comment: @TheCoder It seems that your intention is the latter approach that I describe in my answer. Did you try defining a function that takes a `array2D&` parameter yet?

Comment: @TheCoder: But in your code you use the C parameter as a double, you don't need a vector to store the sum of all the elements of a 3d array. What's the array2D for?

Comment: @user2079303: Yes, I tried and get a different error `error: declaration of 'const double C' shadows a parameter`.

Comment: @TheCoder: If your function is supposed to take a 2D array, why does it take a double instead? Simply don't do that. Problem solved. What is all the fuss?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I tried different combinations one suggested by @user2079303 `(array3D&, array2D&)`, but no success. What I think this suggested option should work but has the error I commented before.

Comment: @TheCoder - The `shadow` error is probably because you have a global variable named C and a local variable in the function also name C. Simply rename one of them and the problem will go away.

Answer (score 0):

(Edit: Answer updated after comments from OP)

Is this what you are looking for:

```
typedef std::vector<double> array1D;
typedef std::vector<array1D> array2D;
typedef std::vector<array2D> array3D;

void computeC(array3D& fp, array2D& C) {
    double tmp = 0.0;

    // Calculate sum of element in 3D array
    for (int x = 0; x < M; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < N; ++y) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
                tmp += fp[x][y][i];
            }
        }
    }

    // Update the 2D array
    for (int x = 0; x < M; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < N; ++y) {
            C[x][y] = tmp;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    array2D C(M, array1D(N, 0));
    array3D fp(M, array2D(N, array1D(5, 0.0)));
    computeC(fp, C);
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
typedef std::vector<double> array1D;
typedef std::vector<array1D> array2D;
typedef std::vector<array2D> array3D;

void computeC(array3D& fp, array2D& C) {
    for (int x = 0; x < M; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < N; ++y) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
                C[x][y] += fp[x][y][i];
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    array2D C(M, array1D(N, 0));
    array3D fp(M, array2D(N, array1D(5, 0.0)));
    computeC(fp, C);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Supposed `M` and `N` are non const `double` values defined elsewhere.

Comment: That's fine, but I still don't get what the OP want to do with the array2D C and why he don't just return a double

Comment: Who said anything about global variables?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - OP wrote it in a comment to the other answer.

Comment: Until it's part of the question or the problem I don't see its relevance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I get the results and the functions is working perfect as desired. Thanks for the help. Working function is:

```
void computeC(array3D& fp, array2D& C) {
    for (int x = 0; x < M; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < N; ++y) {
         C[x][y] = 0.0
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
                C[x][y] += fp[x][y][i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've correctly changed the parameter type to `array2D&` as I suggested. But your function does not appear to do anything with the parameter.

Comment: @user2079303: My function is taking fp as input 3D array, summing all its elements and assign it to C i.e. a 2D array.

Comment: @Bob__: Can you highlight or suggest modifications? As I am not an advanced user, so, I need help if you could do so.

Comment: @TheCoder: You are passing an array2D named C by reference. Fine. Then you declare a variable with the same name C as a double (which is a scalar, 1 number), set it to 0.0 and use it to accumulate the sum. You are not changing any elements of the parameter you passed, you are using something else. See what StillLearnig wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer of StillLearning is the best fit to your question.

Maybe you can get rid of global variables and divide that function into two more basic functionality, like sumOfElements and setElements:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<double> array1D;
typedef std::vector<array1D> array2D;
typedef std::vector<array2D> array3D;

template< typename T>
double sumOfElements (T & a) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for ( auto i : a) sum += sumOfElements(i);
    return sum;
}

template<>
double sumOfElements<array1D> (array1D & a) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for ( auto i : a) sum += i;
    return sum;
}

template< typename T >
void setElements ( double val, T & a) {
    for ( auto & i : a) setElements(val,i);
}

template<>
void setElements<array1D> ( double val, array1D & a) {
    for ( auto & i : a) i = val;
}

int main() {
    double d;
    array2D b(4,array1D(5,0.1));
    array3D c(3,array2D(4,array1D(5,2.0)));


    d = sumOfElements(c);
    std::cout << "Sum of elements: " << d << std::endl;
    setElements(d,b);
    std::cout << "Now all the elements of the array2D are: " << b[2][3] << std::endl;;

    return 0;
}
```